# Chrome - enable 'share audio' by default with navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia

Tags: google-chrome, share, mediadevices, get-display-media

I want to capture tab audio with Chrome. I call

```
navigator.mediaDevices
      .getDisplayMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true,
      })
      .then(stream => {...})
```

but the 'share audio' option is not ticked by default on the Chrome Share Screen.
Is there a way to force the 'share audio' option from the client code ?